# How can I create a pair type in go?

Tags: go

I want to create a pair such as `pair(string, int)`. I know that in go there is no pair type, and I also know that slices can only hold the same data type.

How may I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go doesn't have tuples like some other languages.  You can create a struct type with a string and an int field:

```
type myStruct struct {
    str string
    num int
}
```

Comment: You are right. You don't strictly need tuples - Go structs work ok. Anonymous structs can also be used. Tuples perhaps would be on the "nice to have" list for future Go versions because they may might make code more terse. I'm not sure that this would be a big win though.

Comment: @Rick-777 the multiple return capability eliminates a lot of use cases for tuples.

Comment: Yes, good point. And it uses the stack frame, so it's far more efficient than, say, Scala tuples for multiple return values.

Comment: It would be so nice if something that returned multiple could be accessed the same way as in scala. `func multiple() (int, error) { ...}` . Use `multiple()._1`